# Retrieving data from linkedIn using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linkedin-api

Does anyone have idea about fetching the structured/Unstructured data from Twitter/LinkedIn API using Azure Data Factory? Please let me know if anyone has exposure on this.

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge we don't have directory connector available to fetch the data
Yom may find list of data stores supported here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores

If you need to move data to/from a data store that is not in the Azure Data Factory built-in connector list, here are some extensible options:

1.For database and data warehouse, usually you can find a corresponding ODBC driver, with which you can use generic ODBC connector.
2.For SaaS applications:
If it provides RESTful APIs, you can use generic REST connector.
If it has OData feed, you can use generic OData connector.
If it provides SOAP APIs, you can use generic HTTP connector.
If it has ODBC driver, you can use generic ODBC connector.
3.For others, check if you can load data to or expose data as any ADF supported data stores, e.g. Azure Blob/File/FTP/SFTP/etc, then let ADF pick up from there. You can invoke custom data loading mechanism via Azure Function, Custom activity, Databricks/HDInsight, Web activity, etc.